# Tick Method not Recognizing Variable Change

Tags: java, game-physics

I am currently working on a Pac-Man remake in Java, and I am having a problem with player movement. I use a KeyListener to detect when the W A S or D keys are pressed, and sets a variable as true or false. The variables are up, down, left, right. This works fine, but the "tick" method does not recognize the value change, almost as if there are two variables. For example, I will press the W key and up is set to true. In the tick method, however, up is not true. This also happens when getting the position of the player. It will only get the first position of the player, but after I edit the position in the KeyListener method, the tick method will not recognize that the position has been changed.

I have also found that when I move the position directly from the KeyListener method and print it to the console, it works correctly. But when I print the position from the tick method, it always prints the original position. If I print both, it seems as if there are two variables, because the KeyListener method will always print the correct value, and the tick method will always print the original, but does not reset the KeyListener value.

Sorry if this sounds confusing, please ask if you need me to describe it in a different way.

Anyway, the tick method is being called 60 times every second.

Can someone please help me fix this problem? Help is appreciated.

Here is the class for the Player, containing the tick and KeyListener methods.

```
package com.graysullivan.entities;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.graysullivan.main.Location;

public class Player implements KeyListener {

Location pos;
private int width = 80;
private int height = 80;
private boolean up, down, left, right;

public Player() {
    pos = new Location(360, 701);
}

public void init() {
}

public void tick(double deltaTime) {
//System.out.println(pos.y);
    if(up) {
        System.out.println("up");
        pos.y--;
    } 

    if(down) {
        pos.y++;
    }

    if(left) {
        pos.x--;
    }

    if(right) {
        pos.x++;
    }
}

public void render(Graphics2D g) {
    g.fillRect((int)pos.x,(int)pos.y, 40, 40);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
        up = true;
        System.out.println(up);
    }

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
        down = true;
    }

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        left = true;
    }

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        right = true;
    }

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
        up = false;
    }

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
        down = false;
    }

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        left = false;
    }

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        right = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}
```

Comment: Do you happen to call the tick method from a different thread? If yes then you might have a memory consistency error. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html for more information.

Comment: I think so, my main class implements runnable and starts on a new thread. A method on that thread then calls multiple methods which leads to the tick method. The position variable is being defined on construction, which I believe is called from the default thread. How should I fix it?

Comment: Can you also show the part where `tick` is called?

Comment: Well, it is called from a class which is called from a superclass interface, which is called from another interface, which is called from the main class. So... do you need all of that, or just some?

Comment: Perhaps putting all the source code in GitHub would make it easier.

Comment: I tried to add it to GitHub but for some reason it was making me do some weird thing... so I put it in a pastebin, all of the classes related to this are in here. http://pastebin.com/jsZN6WfP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, there is a part that look suspicious.

In `Game.java` you created an instance of `Player`

```
frame.addKeyListener(new Player());
```

Another instance of `Player` is also created in `LevelLoader.java`

```
Player player = new Player();
```

...which is the one that getting the `tick` method triggered.

They are two different objects which has nothing to do with each other (other than the fact that they are from the same class). Changing a state of one object doesn't change the state of another. What happen in your case is that the first `Player` instance listen to key press but the second instance is getting the `tick` method triggered.

What you need to do is to create a player instance in `Game.java` and pass the object to `LevelLoader.java` (via `StateManager.java`?) instead of creating another instance in `LevelLoader.java` itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to declare `synchronized` on the method which manipulate `up`, `down`, `right`, and `left` to avoid memory consistency error and thread interference.

Something like this:

```
public synchronized void tick(double deltaTime) {
    ...
}
```

Edit: you might want to declare the members with volatile to ensure that the changes in `keyPressed` method happens before the `tick`.

Comment: You mean like `private volatile boolean up, down, left, right` ? Tried that, still nothing.